# Talend Studio : My job worked until print the error " routine signature not found "

Tags: talend

I have created a job in Talend where data comes from an Access database and goes to a Postgres database. Everything was good, my job launched normally, and at one point when I launched or relaunched my codes, the following message appeared:

> [WARN ] 09:26:31 com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Index- unsupported collating sort order SortOrder[1036(0)] for text index (Db=Donnees_irrig_v5.accdb;Table=SR_bd_carthage_MP;Index=0), making read-only
>
> WARNING:routine signature not found for: PUBLIC.LEN(INTEGER)

What I found in the internet is about Java, but I can't translate it in Talend.

Comment: Try to export your job and create a new workspace and then import your job (in fact , it's probably the system routine that have dispeared) , let me know the result

Comment: I have created the new workspace with the same job and the error is still the same : 
' WARNING:routine signature not found for: PUBLIC.LEN(INTEGER) '

(I can't add an image sorry)